# Парсер картинок из публичного канала телеграмм в бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

написал бота обрабатывающего изображения, осталось прикрутить к нему парсер или настроить сам парсер, для того чтобы парсер мог отправлять картинки боту и бот их обрабатывал. Пока даже не знаю с чего начинать.

Comment: Попробуйте библиотеку для клиента телеграмма `telethon`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/16b7916265cc41c4ac72afc0ca5b3c15767622c7/telegram__telethon__examples/print_dialogs.py#L17

Comment: получается в любом случае необходимо будет писать клиент?

Comment: Ага, не думаю, что по другому получится вытащить картинки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел выход, библиотека Pyrogram, в ютубе есть видео под названиями граббер для телеграмма